# What is the correct way to call a method with parameters?

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I am trying to do a Java Assigment in which i have to calculate the area of a rectangle.

This is the given header that sets the rectangleArea method:

```
public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width)
```

Given this header i was wondering which is the correct way to calculate the area by passing values to the method's parameters?

Number 1.

```
public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width)

{
   double area = length * width;
   System.out.println("area");
   return area;
}
rectangleArea (6,3);
```

Number 2.

```
public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width)

{
   double area = length * width;
   System.out.println("area");
   return area;
}

public static void test()
{
  rectangleArea(6,3);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do by calling the same function with same parameter twice?

Comment: I am having difficulties understanding what exactly the question is. The Function is the same in both snippets, right? If you want to call that method outside the class, you'll need the Context (the Class). So if your Class containing that method is called `Rect` then you'll call `Rect.rectangleArea(x,y)`

Comment: The 2 way look like the same, please elaborate your question with what you want to achieve.

Comment: The 2nd way where you have the test() method is more correct. You will need to call test() from your `main` method

Comment: Sorry i am just starting to try learn Java i just want to know which is the correct syntaxis. Can i call the method with the parameters like method_name(parameters); or do i have to put this inside a class (like in exmaple no.2) to be able to successfully pass the parameter values 6 and 3?

Comment: 1 is not valid code, as your call `rectangleArea (6,3);` is not contained in a method. If you try, it won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

Both ways are correct if you asking a proper way to call a method.

Probably case Number one will not be correct under some circumstances because you are calling static method.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a `Test.java` which you can compile (with javac) and run (with java). The run executes the public static method `main` that has a `String[]` parameter.

```
public class Test {

    public static double rectangleArea(double length, double width)
    {
       double area = length * width;
       return area;
       // Or: return length * width;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double area = rectangleArea(6, 3);
        System.out.println("area: " + area);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe we should add that if she put the rectangleArea method in another class - say `Rect` , she'd have to call `Rect.rectangleArea(6,3);`.

Comment: @Fildor Yes `package` and `import` should be early teaching subjects too.

Comment: Ok i am sorry i am just having a difficult time understanding. If i already declared the method rectangleArea then wouldn't be enough to just call it underneeth in the form of method_name(parameters); instead of having to put the call in yet another method like test?

Comment: Maybe your environment is for java training and provides a GUI  to run java right away. But us, normal people, must make a .java file, compile that to a .class file and run that. A .java file contains a "class" a minimal unit. As all this does not concern you, and the first version works, do that. However I would call println _outside_ the function, at the call.

Answer (score 0):

> Both are Correct , Although it depends on your requirement

But you are not using the returned value like

`double no = rectangleArea (6,3)`;

or

```
public static void test()
{
 double no =  rectangleArea(6,3);
}
```